# Hibernate.cfg.xml file not found while executing Junit test cases through Jenkins MVN build

Tags: hibernate, junit

I have a Springboot & Hibernate based project which runs fine in my local (STS), and in Jenkin, which runs from source-code repository.
Now I have developed some Junit test cases which runs perfectly fine in my local (STS). But Build is failing when running through Jenkin. It gives ERROR as "hibernate.cfg.xml" file not found, and hence all test cases are failing. I believe this only because of Junit test cases which is not able to find this cfg file. My all test cases are in standard location of "src/test/java".
My code read like: configuration.configure(new File(hbmFilePath));

To resolve this issue I have placed "hibernate.cfg.xml" in all possible locations so that it could be found, like:->

```
1)src/main/resource/hibernate.cfg.xml
2)src/test/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
3)hibernate.cfg.xml (i.e. at root of source package as well)
```

But still it is not able to find the "hibernate.cfg.xml".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed hbm file path from :

> configuration.configure(new File(hbmFilePath));

into -

> configuration.configure(hbmFilePath);

...and all Junits test cases are running successfully. Meaning to say this approach is able to find hbm file from Test cases.